# Nav bar issues with jquery,css,html5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

got this problem, I'm using jquery as changing to my nav bar witch means, when I'm changing pages
I load into #maincontent div the other pages info.
and problem is that I want to set css rules to totally another page.
and it just doens't work

```
function (data) {

    console.log(data);

    $('#maincontent').load('friends.html #friends_load');

    for( var i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++ ){

        $('#friends_content').append("<br />");
        $('#friends_content').append("<h1>שם:</h1>" + data.data[i].name + "");
        $('#friends_content').append("<span>מזהה משתמש: "+ data.data[i].id +"</span><br/><br/>");
  //      $('#maincontent').append("<span>יום הולדת: "+ data.data[i].picture.data.url +"</span><br/>");

        var image = document.createElement('img');
        image.src = data.data[i].picture.data.url;
        $('#friends_content').append(image)

    }
});
```

now I mean that where #friends_content .. and page will load stuff into that div, but it doens't work, so I dont know how to organize it.
anyhow, if I just put #maincontent all the way, it works.. but how can I control it?

thanks AHEAD!

Answer (score 0):

If #friends_content is an element within the dynamically loaded #friends_load, perhaps this can help: [Jquery: Appending data to a div AFTER ajax load operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1932269/jquery-appending-data-to-a-div-after-ajax-load-operation)?

Comment: thanks you, tried a few ways with that options, seems to be logicly good.. but dones't work for me

Comment: Perhaps you can give some more information? Do you have a link? Can you make a jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/)? What did you try? What are  the errors that you get?